# Find largest document size in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to find the largest document size in MongoDB?

`db.collection.stats()` shows average size, which is not really representative because in my case sizes can differ considerably.

Comment: I don't know what driver you're using, but you should be able to see the [bson size](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/src/bson.h#L141) somehow. Do that and a table-scan to figure out what is the biggest document.

Comment: Not easily, there is no `$documentSize` operator in a MongoDB query and `$size` does something quite different. The onkly real way in most client side drivers, include the javascript one is to use the client side helper.

Comment: @Sammaye: you can [use aggregation to calculate the sizes of the largest suspected fields on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb/56048602#56048602). This solution is much faster than any other the other answers.

Comment: @DanDascalescu not really, it does the exact same as the accepted answer https://github.com/eladnava/mongodb-largest-documents/blob/master/lib/logic.js#L33

Comment: @Sammaye: the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957505/1269037) transfers the entire collection from the server to the client. The [solution I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb/56048602#56048602) does all the processing on the server.

Comment: @DanDascalescu actually the accepted answer transfers the data to wherever the console being used is, and in distributed networks that's no different to running it on a different server altogether, there is no "server-side" and MongoDB Inc used to try to knock into everyone's heads in the early days

Comment: @Sammaye: I'm talking about the common case of the client being your developer laptop, and the server being something like mLab, Mongo Atlas, Scalegrid etc. or, another server somewhere in the cloud that you're not SSH-ing into.

Comment: @DanDascalescu umm, why are you not using good security practices and using a proxyed jump box bastion server? This sounds like an issue with you using production resources in a local environment which breaks good network design

Comment: @Sammaye: mLab doesn't have that, and I'm using a reporting view on a production collection in a local environment. Anyway, I think this is avoiding the point of how much data is being transferred between the server and the local client.

Comment: @DanDascalescu no it won't, they won't do everything for you, they will automate the setup of sets, and no it isn't, because how much is being transferred depends on where your client is, coming back to the point "there is no sever-side in a distributed environment"

Comment: @DanDascalescu you could argue that if you translate the accepted answer to a served binary, such as a PHP application, then it could justify doing the aggregation framework, however, I note that your current implementation of the query actually returns a huge amount of data since it doesn't actually limit. It simply counts the size of each docs and then returns that, so while, yes, it would be less, it wouldn't be crazy less

Comment: @DanDascalescu I will close with saying this: I do not recommend doing any schema design this way if you are using this in a PHP application or whatever

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addField: {
      objectSize: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      objectSize: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      objectSize: 0,
    },
  },
]);

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use a small shell script to get this value.

**Note**: this will perform a full table scan, which will be slow on large collections.

```js
let max = 0, id = null;
db.test.find().forEach(doc => {
    const size = Object.bsonsize(doc); 
    if(size > max) {
        max = size;
        id = doc._id;
    } 
});
print(id, max);
```

Comment: I assume this size is in bytes?

Comment: @akki, yes, bsonsize returns bytes value (according to [mognodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous)

Comment: Is there a way to NOT load every document to client to calc its size? Perhaps using aggregation somehow.

Comment: Work! Very slow, but Work!!!

Answer (score 28):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the new aggregation operator [`$bsonSize`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/#exp._S_bsonSize) returns the size in bytes of a given document when encoded as BSON.

Thus, in order to find the bson size of the document whose size is the biggest:

```
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5e6abb2893c609b43d95a985"), "a" : 1, "b" : "hello" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5e6abb2893c609b43d95a986"), "c" : 1000, "a" : "world" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5e6abb2893c609b43d95a987"), "d" : 2 }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    max: { $max: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : null, "max" : 46 }
```

This:

- `$group`s all items together
- `$project`s the `$max` of documents' `$bsonSize`
- [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) represents the current document for which we get the bsonsize

Comment: This solution worked fine for me - thanks!

Comment: as of 2022, this is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: How can you pull the document id?

Comment: @AustinMutschler you should be able to work with the document with max size using a `$top` stage rather than a `$group` stage.

Answer (score 26):

Note: this will attempt to store the whole result set in memory (from `.toArray`) . Careful on big data sets. Do not use in production! Abishek's answer has the advantage of working over a cursor instead of across an in memory array.

If you also want the _id, try this. Given a collection called "requests" :

```
// Creates a sorted list, then takes the max
db.requests.find().toArray().map(function(request) { return {size:Object.bsonsize(request), _id:request._id}; }).sort(function(a, b) { return a.size-b.size; }).pop();

// { "size" : 3333, "_id" : "someUniqueIdHere" }
```

Comment: After running the accepted answer, this is the next script that anyone would want to run!

Comment: I get an error running this: Error: assertion src\mongo\util\net\message_port.cpp:195 src/mongo/shell/query.js:113

Comment: This is a better answer than foreach loop

Comment: This should _not_ be the accepted answer. Calling `toArray()` on a large collection could crash the client. You can't pull 10 TB of data into the client's memory and then try to `map` it. You need to iterate it and let the driver handle batching.

Comment: @PeteGarafano It says fairly clearly in the answer that it will pull it all into memory and is not for production. Dont down vote me because you copy and paste into prod.

Comment: @MikeGraf I did not down vote because "copy and paste into prod". I down voted this because I feel this qualifies under the [recommendations given by StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) on when to down vote an issue. I'm sorry you feel otherwise, however I stand by my vote.

Comment: @PeteGarafano Presumably this part `and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`  .  I'll see if I can update soon.

Comment: Definitely not for production with many docs but it works like a charm on my local machine with sample data from the production database.

Comment: Here's a much faster solution using [using aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb/56048602#56048602), which also doesn't require bringing the whole result set on the client.

Answer (score 18):

Finding the largest documents in a MongoDB collection can be ~100x faster than the other answers using the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) and a tiny bit of knowledge about the documents in the collection. Also, you'll get the results in seconds, vs. minutes with the other approaches (`forEach`, or worse, getting all documents to the client).

You need to know which field(s) in your document might be the largest ones - *which you almost always will know*. There are only two practical<sup>1</sup> MongoDB [types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) that can have variable sizes:

- arrays
- strings

The aggregation framework can calculate the length of each. Note that you won't get the size in bytes for arrays, but the length in elements. However, what matters more typically is *which* the outlier documents are, not exactly how many bytes they take.

Here's how it's done for arrays. As an example, let's say we have a collections of users in a social network and we suspect the array `friends.ids` might be very large (in practice you should probably keep a separate field like `friendsCount` in sync with the array, but for the sake of example, we'll assume that's not available):

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        'friends.ids': { $exists: true }
    }},
    { $project: { 
        sizeLargestField: { $size: '$friends.ids' } 
    }},
    { $sort: {
        sizeLargestField: -1
    }},
])
```

The key is to use the [`$size` aggregation pipeline operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/). It only works on arrays though, so what about text fields? We can use the [`$strLenBytes` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/). Let's say we suspect the `bio` field might also be very large:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        bio: { $exists: true }
    }},
    { $project: { 
        sizeLargestField: { $strLenBytes: '$bio' } 
    }},
    { $sort: {
        sizeLargestField: -1
    }},
])
```

You can also combine `$size` and `$strLenBytes` using `$sum` to calculate the size of multiple fields. In the vast majority of cases, [20% of the fields will take up 80% of the size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) (if not 10/90 or even 1/99), and large fields must be either strings or arrays.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Technically, the rarely used `binData` type can also have variable size.</sup>

Comment: @Sammaye the code in the accepted answer executes by client shell, not by databse server. So it loads to the client every document one by one using cursor, calculates it's size, and determines the largest one. Yes, it doesn't store the full collection in client's memory, but it still needs to transfer data via network. So that approach isn't quite usefull for large collections.

Comment: @Sammaye I'm not exactly sure how aggregation transfers data between shards, but in single server configuration it's a good point if you can avoid transfering the full collection and calculate everything on the server. Even though if db loads all the data into it's memory.

Comment: One thing to note would be that much of the speedup is likely coming from the client/server round trip where the client is your laptop and the server is a remote db host across WAN. So it would be interesting (i suspect negligible) how must faster it would be when running other client scripted vs agg framework solutions _on the mongodb host_ (ie you connect to the db on localhost) ...

Answer (score 3):

Well.. this is an old question.. but - I thought to share my cent about it

My approach - use Mongo `mapReduce` function

First - let's get the size for each document

```
db.myColection.mapReduce
(
   function() { emit(this._id, Object.bsonsize(this)) }, // map the result to be an id / size pair for each document
   function(key, val) { return val }, // val = document size value (single value for each document)
   { 
       query: {}, // query all documents
       out: { inline: 1 } // just return result (don't create a new collection for it)
   } 
)
```

This will return all documents sizes although it worth mentioning that saving it as a collection is a better approach (the result is an array of results inside the `result` field)

Second - let's get the max size of document by manipulating this query

```
db.metadata.mapReduce
(
    function() { emit(0, Object.bsonsize(this))}, // mapping a fake id (0) and use the document size as value
    function(key, vals) { return Math.max.apply(Math, vals) }, // use Math.max function to get max value from vals (each val = document size)
    { query: {}, out: { inline: 1 } } // same as first example
)
```

Which will provide you a single result with value equals to the max document size

**In short:**

you may want to use the first example and save its output as a collection (change `out` option to the name of collection you want) and applying further aggregations on it (max size, min size, etc.)

*-OR-*

you may want to use a single query (the second option) for getting a single stat (min, max, avg, etc.)

Comment: Your second example worked great for small data sets but actually managed to take my (hosted) server down with an out-of-memory error when run on a collection with about 400k documents.  What is consuming all the memory?  Can it really just not handle producing an array with 400k elements to pass to the reduce function?  The doc says it should handle up to half Mongo's 16MB limit as a value argument to emit and as input to reduce.  This should only be returning  8 bytes per emit!  Shouldn't it call reduce multiple times if it nears memory limits?  What is going on here?

Comment: That's an important benchmark - thank you for sharing this data with us! To your question: I think it depends on 2 factors - first: available resources on hosted machine and second - the amount of load this machine handled when you executed your query (was it the only think handled by Mongo?). Nevertheless, this behavior is far from being accepted - you shouldn't be able to "take down" your server by performing such an activity. I find this disturbing. In person,I think this comment should turn into a question (probably at https://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get more details about the records (i.e. documents) which has highest size

1. Calculate size
2. Sort basis calculated size
3. Limit to your desired number of records
4. (Optionaly) Project to get only the fields which you want.

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        bsonsize: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $sort: { bsonsize: -1 }},
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        bsonsize: 1
    }}
])
```

Note: (Performance)
This will scan entire collection. If you have vert large collection, then it can consume lot of IOPS. Run when database is at lowest activity level.

My collection contained 85 Million Records and its size was 30GB. It took 75 seconds to run.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a huge collection, loading it all at once into memory will not work, since you'll need more RAM than the size of the entire collection for that to work.

Instead, you can process the entire collection in batches using the following package I created:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-largest-documents

All you have to do is provide the MongoDB connection string and collection name. The script will output the top X largest documents when it finishes traversing the entire collection in batches.

[image: Preview]

Comment: This is exactly what the built in cursor allows for. It streams the data rather than storing the entire collection to ram.

Comment: Hi @dmo, could you please provide a command to achieve this via the built-in cursor?

Comment: collection.find() returns a cursor. The cursor is a stream of data. So in JS you can do something like this... https://jsfiddle.net/ro6efkdz/

Comment: @dmo: how does that `cursor.on('data', ...)` approach compare with [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb/16957505#16957505)? Is it any faster? Does it consume any less memory?

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense, the default cursor of any client driver would not load the collection into memory, in fact if you were to go down the aggregation framework route as Dan mentioned, then it would load that entire result set into memory. It is good to note that does exactly the same as the accepted answer, only in node.js https://github.com/eladnava/mongodb-largest-documents/blob/master/lib/logic.js#L33

Answer (score 0):

To use on mongosh directly, bringing the doc _id

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    max: { $max: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } },
    id: { $first: '$_id'} 
  }}
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by [Elad Nana's package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-largest-documents), but usable in a MongoDB console :

```js
function biggest(collection, limit=100, sort_delta=100) {
  var documents = [];
  cursor = collection.find().readPref("nearest");
  while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next();
    var size = Object.bsonsize(doc);
    if (documents.length < limit || size > documents[limit-1].size) {
      documents.push({ id: doc._id.toString(), size: size });
    }
    if (documents.length > (limit + sort_delta) || !cursor.hasNext()) {
      documents.sort(function (first, second) {
        return second.size - first.size;
      });
      documents = documents.slice(0, limit);
    }
  }
  return documents;
}; biggest(db.collection)
```

- Uses cursor
- Gives a list of the `limit` biggest documents, not just the biggest
- Sort & cut output list to `limit` every `sort_delta`
- Use `nearest` as [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) (you might also want to use `rs.slaveOk()` on the connection to be able to list collections if you're on a slave node)

Answer (score -1):

As [Xavier Guihot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297144/xavier-guihot) already mentioned, a new [$bsonSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/) aggregation operator was introduced in Mongo 4.4, which can give you the size of the object in bytes. In addition to that just wanted to provide my own example and some stats.

#### Usage example:

```
// I had an `orders` collection in the following format
[
  {
    "uuid": "64178854-8c0f-4791-9e9f-8d6767849bda",
    "status": "new",
    ...
  },
  {
    "uuid": "5145d7f1-e54c-44d9-8c10-ca3ce6f472d6",
    "status": "complete",
    ...
  },
  ...
];

// and I've run the following query to get documents' size
db.getCollection("orders").aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: { status: "complete" } // pre-filtered only completed orders
    },
    {
      $project: {
        uuid: 1,
        size: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } // added object size
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: { size: -1 }
    },
  ],
  { allowDiskUse: true } // required as I had huge amount of data
);
```

as a result, I received a list of documents by size in descending order.

#### Stats:

For the collection of ~3M records and ~70GB size in total, the query above took ~6.5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possible solution

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addField: {
      objectSize: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      objectSize: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      objectSize: 0,
    },
  },
]);
```