# Find biggest document in Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb

I would like to find the biggest document in a mongo collection. "Biggest" would mean the one that takes up the most units towards the 16MB document size limit. Bonus points for finding that document's _id too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a collection called "requests" :

```
db.requests.find().toArray().map(function(request) { return {size:Object.bsonsize(request), _id:request._id}; }).sort(function(a, b) { return a.size-b.size; }).pop();

// { "size" : 3333, "_id" : "someUniqueIdHere" }
```

Comment: This is well documented somewhere

Comment: yup, right here :D  ... google and DDG searches didnt find anything helpful in the top 10.

Comment: What about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb ? Plus that method is more efficient and less heavy

Comment: It should be noted that link was the first result when searching for "mongodb find largest document" on Google

Comment: I think I looked at that one and wanted the answer of what is the biggest, not the size of every document. Nonetheless, i voted to close this, or should I delete it?

Comment: Probably vote to close I see you added your answer there which is a good idea