# Find largest document in MongoDB WITHOUT loading every document client side

Tags: mongodb

I read [Find largest document size in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb) and [Find biggest document in Mongo Collection [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407202/find-biggest-document-in-mongo-collection?noredirect=1&lq=1).
In those questions, no answer has a solution that does not imply to load every document on the client's side, but it is also not clearly stated as impossible.

Hence this question, is it even possible to find out which documents are the largest **without** having every single one going across the wire?

---

For my personal use case, it's about querying a single collection of
450 000+ documents weighing over 10.5 GB.

Comment: Can you define largest? Is it the one that has the longest BSON? Or the one that has greatest aggregate length of all property values? Or the one that takes more space, including record padding? Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Good comment.
I mean the largest as in the one(s) that takes most space.
I don't think the record padding would matter much, but if there's an answer for both, I'm interested in both.

Comment: Another thing, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "load every document on the client's side". It is possible to run a query on server that is virtually co-located with MongoDB database, then reduce the data and send it. What is "client's side" in this case?

Comment: "Client side" being anything but the database (like my PC, or the server where my app is running). The whole idea is to avoid downloading GBs of data and get the database to analyze itself instead.