# Mongodb Out of Memory while total DB size < available RAM

Tags: mongodb, memory

I have read what I could find on memory consumption for MongoDB, but the gist of what I understood was that everything was handled by the OS, and if no memory is available the data will be read from disk, then replace something else in memory.

I have a pretty small database

```
    > db.stats()
    {
            "db" : "prod",
            "collections" : 11,
            "objects" : 2022,
            "avgObjSize" : 43469.34915924827,
            "dataSize" : 87895024,
            "storageSize" : 113283072,
            "numExtents" : 30,
            "indexes" : 10,
            "indexSize" : 4840192,
            "fileSize" : 201326592,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "extentFreeList" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalSize" : 0
            },
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                    "major" : 4,
                    "minor" : 22
            },
            "ok" : 1
    }
```

with a small server with 1GB of RAM. Seeing the size of the DB (~100MB), I would assume 1GB of RAM should be plenty.

I have however been having Out of Memory errors for some time now, first infrequently (one every 2-3 weeks), and almost twice a day now.

I'm at a loss as to what could cause these issues, and thought that I may be missing something completely.

I ran what diagnosis I found on the net:

- ulimit

  ```
  $ ulimit -a
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  pending signals                 (-i) 7826
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  open files                      (-n) 1024
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 7826
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited
  ```
- mongod version is 3.0.12
- OS info:

  ```
  NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
  VERSION="2015.03"
  ID="amzn"
  ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
  VERSION_ID="2015.03"
  PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03"
  ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
  CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.03:ga"
  HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
  Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.03
  ```
- db.serverStatus() is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6698KJbW). Edit: looking at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#memory-status

  > If mem.virtual value is significantly larger than mem.mapped (e.g. 3 or more times), this may indicate a memory leak.

  So maybe something to look at
- Swap is enabled
- `free -m` execution before launching MongoDB

  ```
  $ free -m
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:           996         60        935          0          5         19
  -/+ buffers/cache:         36        959
  Swap:         4095          9       4086
  ```

  and right after launch (launching + running the command immediately)

  ```
  $ free -m
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:           996        925         71          0          5        834
  -/+ buffers/cache:         84        911
  Swap:         4095          9       4086
  ```
- `mongostat` run

  ```
  $ mongostat
  insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize    res faults qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    9 07:04:55
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    9 07:04:56
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     3|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0  196b    11k    9 07:04:57
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    9 07:04:58
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0  133b    10k    9 07:04:59
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.6G 764.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    9 07:05:00
  ```
- Running `mongostat` a few hours later show an increase in res memory (Edit: re-running serverStatus() [shows no increase in mem.resident](http://pastebin.com/jvWyAS1j) though)

  ```
  $ mongostat
  insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize    res faults qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      8   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    8 10:39:50
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    8 10:39:51
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    8 10:39:52
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    8 10:39:53
      *0    *0     *0     *0       0     4|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0  250b    11k    8 10:39:54
      *0     2     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0  183b    11k    8 10:39:55
      *0     1     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 688.0M  7.7G 856.0M      0   0|0   0|0  131b    11k    8 10:39:56
  ```
- `swapon -s`

  ```
  $ swapon -s
  Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
  /swapfile                               file    4194300 10344   -1
  ```

Edit: I've setup MongoDB Cloud Monitoring, and the issue just reoccurred. [This is the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpjZ4.jpg), and the mongo process was killed at 02:29

Do you have any idea what may be causing the issue? Or hints into where I should look?

Thanks for your help!

Seb

Comment: What is your maximum document size? Currently, [The maximum BSON document size is 16 MBS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)

Comment: @michael_j_ward using the script proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953282/find-largest-document-size-in-mongodb, I queried my two most likely candidates for big objets, and got a max size of `{ "size" : 1851832, "_id" : ObjectId("57616746e4b0d559c609b680") }`

Comment: is this linux box? swap enabled?

Comment: It's Amazon Linux AMI. Swap is enabled. Adding info to the OP